# Check onload and onerror using JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Using HTML I could manually put this into the body

```
<img style="display:none;"
onload="Success('test')"
onerror="Fail('test')"
src="http://example.com/test.png"
/>
```

Is there anyway to do this check using jQuery or JavaScript?

Edit: I want to avoid using HTML and inserting image manually. I am trying to accomplish the check using just jQuery/JS.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.. same thing in jQuery would be this

```
​$('img').load(function(){ // when loaded successfully
   console.log('success');  
}).error(function(){  // when theres an error
   console.log('error');  
});​​​​​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/yAfLE/)

or

```
$('img').on({
    load: function(){

    }, 
    error: function(){

    }
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/D7pMP/)

**EDIT:**

If you want it in pure javascript you can do something like this

```
$('<img/>',{ // <-- create the element
      src:'http://wichitaatbat.com/wp-content/uploads/Soccer-Ball.png'
}).load(function(){
    console.log('success');
}).error(function(){
    console.log('error');  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/LCkkn/

Comment: How can I check the if there is an error on image WITHOUT using HTML? Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: @user1530249 What are you talking about?  So you want to use javascript only with no html?

Comment: Yea, would this be possible? Checking if the image exists using only jQuery/JS code?

Answer (score 1):

For `error`, jquery would work in this fashion:

```
$('img').on('error', function(e) {

});
```

Same for `load`:

```
$('img').on('load', function(e) {

});
```

Comment: How can I check the if there is an error on image WITHOUT using HTML? Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure `JavaScript` like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    var img = new Image();   // Create new image element

    img.onload = function(){
      // your code
    };

    img.onerror = function() {
      // your code
    };

    img.src = 'yourImage.png'; // Set source path

</script>
```

You can try this approach [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuaP8/).